# Importar y exportar datos en Python

Tags: python, python-import, exportar

estoy haciendo un programa en el cual te aparecen pokemones de manera aleatoria y estos están definidos por rareza. Lo que pasa es que para que el nombre de los pokemones aparezca hay que escribirlos en el programa y me parece demasiado engorroso ya que el programa se miraria gigante si le pongo todos los nombres en el mismo archivo. Quisiera saber si hay alguna manera de hacer la lista en un archivo o script de python aparte y desde mi programa general mandar a llamar a ese otro programa. les dejo una muestra de mi codigo.

```
import random
accion =input("¿Que deseas hacer?[PK, Exit.]: ")#Establecer que va a hacer el programa según el usuario
pkty = random.randint(1,1000)
if 'pk' == accion.lower():
    rareza = random.randint(1, 1000)

    if 1 <= rareza <= 450:
        a = 'Comun'
    if 451 <= rareza <= 800:
        a = 'Pc'
    if 801 <= rareza <= 950:
        a = 'raro'
    if 951 <= rareza <= 990:
        a = 'epico'
    if 991 <= rareza <= 1000:
        a = 'legendario'
    if 'comun' == a.lower():
        print(" Tu pokemon es: " + random.choice(
            ("Magnemite", "Geodude", "Pidgey", "Machamp", "Magikarp", "Abra", "Caterpie", "Metapod",
             "Weedle", "Kakuna", "Beedril")))
    if 'pc' == a.lower():
        print(" Tu pokemon es: " + random.choice(("Fearow", "Bellsprout", "Jinx", "Tauros")))
    if 'raro' == a.lower():
        print(" Tu pokemon es: " + random.choice(("Alakazam", "Cleafairy", "Pikachu")))
    if 'epico' == a.lower():
        print(" Tu pokemon es: " + random.choice(("Charmander", "Bulbasaur")))
    if 'legendario' == a.lower():
        print("Tu pokemon es: Mewtwo")

elif 'exit' == accion.lower():
    print("Hasta la próxima")
```

En la parte de los prints es que digo ya que si pongo los 151 nombres me quedaría un archivo inmenso

Comment: Algo que podrías hacer es poner los pokemones en una base de datos con un [programa externo](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) y luego [usar python](https://docs.python.org/es/3/library/sqlite3.html) para obtener uno de ellos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías crear un fichero JSON con los nombres y sus rarezas. Se me ocurre algo asi:

pokemon.json

```
{
    "rareza_alta": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ],
    "rareza_media": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ],
    "rareza_baja": [
        "a",
        "b",
        "c"
    ]
}
```

Y para poder leer esos nombres:

```
import json

with open('pokemon.json') as a:
    pokemon = json.load(a)
```

Por ende, si haces...

```
print(pokemon['rareza_alta'][0])
>> a
```

Solo reemplaza "a, b, c" con los nombres reales que correspondan.

Cualquier cosa me escribes, suerte!